# WPF IEnumerable<T> vs IQueryable<T> as DataSource

Tags: wpf, ienumerable, datasource, iqueryable

I have a **WPF ListView** and I bind it to a `IEnumerable<T>` collection.
Everything works fine, but when I bind it to the `IQueryable<T>` collection, there are no items in list anymore.. Why? Is it not **observable** or what?
When I look at the definition:

```
public interface IQueryable<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable, IEnumerable
```

and

```
public interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable
```

so where is the problem?

Comment: Hah... just curious... what was it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, as you correctly point out, these types are compatible.  Turn on debugging in your binding and try it.  Maybe the output will be a clue.  It's likely something else besides the type you are binding to.

Anyway, here's the code.  Put this in and watch your output window when your view loads.  If it's Greek to you, just edit your post with the output from your output window.

```
 <Window …
    xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    />

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Caption, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" … />
```