# IEnumerable vs IQueryable for Business Logic or DAL return Types

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, data-access-layer

I know these questions have been asked before, I'll start by listing a few of them (the ones I've read so far):

- [IEnumerable vs IQueryable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704288/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable)
- [List, IList, IEnumerable, IQueryable, ICollection, which is most flexible return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559868/list-ilist-ienumerable-iqueryable-icollection-which-is-most-flexible-return)
- [Returning IEnumerable<T> vs. IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet)
- [IEnumerable<T> as return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381208/ienumerablet-as-return-type)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712253/ienumerable-and-iqueryable
- [Views with business logic vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357830/views-with-business-logic-vs-code)
- [WPF IEnumerable<T> vs IQueryable<T> as DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226036/wpf-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet-as-datasource)
- [IEnumerable<T> VS IList<T> VS IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603545/ienumerablet-vs-ilistt-vs-iqueryablet)
- [What interface should my service return? IQueryable, IList, IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681962/what-interface-should-my-service-return-iqueryable-ilist-ienumerable)
- [Should I return IEnumerable<T> or IQueryable<T> from my DAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039262/should-i-return-ienumerablet-or-iqueryablet-from-my-dal)

As you can see, there's some great resources on SO alone on the subject, but there is one question/section of the question I'm still not sure about having read these all through.

I'm primarily concerned with the IEnumerable vs IQueryable question, and more specifically the *coupling* between the DAL and it's *consumers*.

I've found varying opinions suggested regarding the two interfaces, which have been great.  However, I'm concerned with the implications of a DAL returning IQueryable.  As I understand it IQueryable suggest/implies that there is a Linq Provider under the hood.  That's concern number one - what if the DAL suddenly requires data from a non-Linq provided source?  The following would work, but is it more of a hack?

```
public static IQueryable<Product> GetAll()
{
    // this function used to use a L2S context or similar to return data 
    // from a database, however, now it uses a non linq provider

    // simulate the non linq provider...
    List<Product> results = new List<Product> { new Product() };
    return results.AsQueryable();
}
```

So I can use the AsQueryable() extension though I don't admit to knowing exactly what this does?  I always imagine IQueryables as being the underlying expression trees which we can append as necessary until we're ready to *perform* our query and fetch the results.

I could rectify this by changing the return type of the function to IEnumerable.  I can then return IQueryable from the function because it inherits IEnumerable, and I get to keep the deferred loading.  What I lose is the ability to append to the query expression:

```
var results = SomeClass.GetAll().Where(x => x.ProductTypeId == 5);
```

When returning IQueryable, as I understand it, this would simply append the expression.  When returning IEnumerable, despite maintaining the deferred loading, the expression has to be evaluated so the results will be brought to memory and enumerated through to filter out incorrect ProductTypeIds.

How do other people get round this?

- Provide more functions in the DAL - GetAllByProductType, GetAllByStartDate,... etc
- Provide an overload that accepts predicates? i.e.

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<Product> GetAll(Predicate<Product> predicate)
  {

      List<Product> results = new List<Product> { new Product() };
      return results.Where(x => predicate(x));
  }
  ```

One last part (Sorry, I know, really long question!).

I found IEnumerable to be the most recommended across all the questions I checked, but what about the deferred loadings' requirement for a datacontext to be available?  As I understand it, if your function returns IEnumerable, but you return IQueryable, the IQueryable is reliant on an underlying datacontext.  Because the result at this stage is actually an expression and nothing has been brought to memory, you cannot guarantee that the DAL's/function's consumer is going to *perform* the query, nor when.  So do I have to keep the instance of the context that the results were derived from available somehow?  Is this how/why the Unit of Work pattern comes into play?

Summary of the questions for clarity ( did a search for "?"...):

1. If using IQueryable as a return type, are you too tightly coupling your UI/Business Logic to Linq Providers?
2. Is using the AsQueryable() extension a good idea if you suddenly need to return data from a non-Linq Provided source?
3. Anyone have a good link describing how for example converting a standard list to AsQueryable works, what it actually does?
4. How do you handle additional filtering requirements supplied by business logic to your DAL?
5. It seems the deferred loading of both IEnumerable and IQueryable are subject to maintaining the underlying provider, should I be using a Unit of Work pattern or something else to handle this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think one shouldnt base deferred loading mechanisms around the functionality of IQueryable.

Comment: Could you ellaborate a little for me please @Urban?  I think, if I understand you, that I'm in agreement.  Our current project is returning IQueryable and it just doesn't feel _right_, despite the extra functionality and convinience it provides in the Business and even Presentation Layers.

Comment: I think while it is nice to have IQueryable defer the load to the last possible moment, this is really meant to be while you construct your query. As you already stated, handing that out would require you to keep the context alive, which you probably cant guarantee. I would rather work with a class that defines and executes my query and let it return an IEnumerable. I might be wrong though :)

Comment: @Urban, I agree completely, but then bear in mind by simply changing the functions return to IEnumerable<T>, I still maintain the deferred load from the query.  I'm still left with the issue of having to maintain the context I think?

Comment: Your IEnumerable<T> would be a fully loaded list. You probably would work with a list in your method and pass it out as IEnumerable or IList

Comment: That's the thing though @Urban, the result doesn't become a fully loaded list if you change the function return type to IEnumerable<T>.  Only if you append AsEnumerable() for example to the back of the query will it load the list.  We thought the same at first, then realised that because IQueryable inherits IEnumerable, there is no implicit casting required, and the IQueryable can be returned as-is.  That then maintains the deferred loading and requires the context be kept alive until the consumer attempts to Enumerate the results.  That make sense?

Comment: It seems i was not clear enough, sorry for that: I suggested working with a List internally and pass it out as (a then fully loaded) IEnumerable<T>. But "in reality" it would be a List<T>. If you are not comfortable with this you might, as Marc suggested, also return an IList<T>. That way nobody will be confused if the thing they get will need to be initially executed or not.

Comment: Ah, I understand now @Urban, I saw @Marc suggest something similar in one of his comments.  I think I prefer IList<T> personally because if using IEnumerable<T>, it's only a matter of time before someone forgets to add ToList() and suddenly you have sections of code reliant on the underlying DataContext's life - which can be a nightmare to debug!  With IList you can't pass out a reference to context by accident (this way at least).  It also lends itself well to SOA I think, but I guess it's down to personal preference. ;-)  Thanks for all your input on this question!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. well, you aren't strictly coupled to any specific provider, but as a re-phrasing of that: you can't easily *test* the code, since each provider has different supported features (meaning: what works for one might not work for another - even something like `.Single()`)
2. I don't think so, if there is *any* question in your mind about ever changing provider - see above
3. it just provides a decorated wrapper that uses `.Compile()` on any lambdas, and uses LINQ-to-Objects instead. Note LINQ-to-Objects has *more* support than any other provider, so this won't be an issue - except that it means that any "mocks" using this approach don't really test your actual code *at all* and are largely pointless (IMO)
4. yeah, tricky - see below
5. yeah, tricky - see below

Personally, I'd prefer well defined APIs here that take known parameters and return a *loaded* `List<T>` or `IList<T>` (or similar) of results; this gives you a testable/mockable API, and doesn't leave you at the mercy of deferred execution (closed connection hell, etc). It also means that any differences between providers is handled *internally* to the implementation of your data layer. It also makes a much closer fit for calling scenarios such as web-services, etc.

In short; given a choice between `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`, I choose neither - opting instead to use `IList<T>` or `List<T>`. If I need additional filtering, then either:

1. I'll add that to the existing API via parameters, and do the filtering inside my data layer
2. I'll accept that oversized data is coming back, which I then need to filter out at the caller

Comment: Could you glarify for me why would you prefer IList<T> or List<T> to IEnumerable? I always had this thought that returning a mutable List is kind of not a good practice, so returning IEnumerable is preferred. Would like to see a different view on this

Comment: @UrbanEsc why *not* return a list? that list is unique to the caller. If they want to put something else in it for their own purposes, that is their problem. It doesn't affect anything else.

Comment: I see your point and am not strictly opposed. As i said i always thought it would be best practice to go for the lowest common interface. So most likely the caller expects a list of things which they can iterate through and dont need modification of this list, right? Do i understand you correctly and the reason for you using a list instead of IEnumerable is because you prefer it, more or less, its not a technical thing.

Comment: @UrbanEsc if you aren't sold on `IList<T>`, then consider returning `IEnumerable<T>`, but where the actual thing *is* a list. It still solves most of the problems (including deferred execution). This is what we do from "dapper", as it happens (unless you set `buffered = false`, when we return raw `IEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: Thanks for the glarification, yes that is the way we prefer to do it.

Comment: Excellent answer Marc, and does clear things up for me.  I did wonder if I was digging my own hole by limiting return types to IEnumerable and IQueryable (like you said, due to disposed context issues), but then reading through the links of similar questions I found that they were the most common/suggested.  All I was after really was the best format for decoupling this layer, just in a roundabout way, and IList certainly does that so thanks!

Comment: @Smudge202 one HUGE advantage of list - the caller *knows* they can query the length cheaply, and iterate it as many times as they like, and take the 3rd item cheaply, etc

Comment: Absolutely @Marc, however due to our current DAL returning IQueryable our Business Logic has come to depend upon being able to append to the query expressions.  Pros and Cons I guess, it had been remarkably convinient to adjust the query filtering based on business logic so I'm now contemplating which of your last two points would be the best approach to maintain as much of this flexibility as possible whilst providing the decoupling we're looking for.

Comment: @Smudge202 returning `IQueryable<T>` is pointless and adds (a little) overhead, if the data isn't really a query. So I'd go `IEnumerable<T>` within your constraints

Comment: @Marc, understood.  The `AsQueryable()` extension isn't actually used often in our project - if at all, it was more of an outside case to be aware of.  What we've been doing is appending the `IQueryable<T>` within business logic because we found the performance compared to working for example on a `List<T>` was a considerable improvement.  Not to worry though, I think we can work out the rest of the finer points.  Thanks again!