# Getter property with async method doesn't finish executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, dapper

**Problem**: method doesn't finish executing (no exception, http request in `pending` status).

I have to implement next interface:

```
public interface IQueryableUserStore<TUser, in TKey> : IUserStore<TUser, TKey>, IDisposable where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
{
    IQueryable<TUser> Users { get; }
}
```

I did it like this:

```
public IQueryable<User> Users {
    get { return (this._userRepository.GetAll().Result).AsQueryable(); }
}
```

Here is `GetAll()` implementation:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAll() {
    const string query = @"
        select * from [dbo].[User]
    ";

    return (await this._db.QueryAsync<User>(query, new {}));
}
```

**Edit:** I remove async behavior from method and method call and it works. But why shouldn't it works with async?

This works:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetAll() {
    const string query = @"
        select * from [dbo].[User]
    ";

    return this._db.Query<User>(query, new {}).AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to `await` as well when returning from `get`.

Comment: @Amit Kumar Ghosh, there is `GetAll().Result`, which should provide `await` behavior, isn't it?

Comment: `IQueryable<T>` is `IEnumable<T>`. `IEnumerable`'s are not evaluated until you force them to. Some tips / explanation available on an old question of mine here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677722/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable-for-business-logic-or-dal-return-types -< i.e. I think you're confusing async behaviour with the deferred loading of IEnumerable?

Comment: @George Vovos, yeap, looks like it isn't connection issue, bcz with  synchronous version it works like a charm

Comment: @Smudge202, looks like i'm confused about this, could you please provide an answer with simple explanation?

Comment: You are probably deadlocking. Using `.Result` is bad in asp.net and in winforms. See [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: @Crowcoder, yeah, maybe you are right, but i can't type `async` in property getter

Comment: Try using [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Change the `GetAll` method to force the enumeration: `return (await this._db.QueryAsync<User>(query, new {})).ToList();` (`ToList` added to the end of the line). Otherwise, all you're doing is returning an unloaded `IEnumerable` which contains all the query mechanics required to query the database; not actually performing the query and returning results.

Answer (score 2):

[`Task.Result` can easily cause deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog.

You need to decide if you want your database access to be synchronous or asynchronous. If synchronous, then go synchronous all the way:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetAll() {
  const string query = @"
    select * from [dbo].[User]
  ";

  return this._db.Query<User>(query, new {}).AsQueryable();
}
```

If asynchronous, then go asynchronous all the way:

```
public interface IQueryableUserStore<TUser, in TKey> : IUserStore<TUser, TKey>, IDisposable where TUser : class, IUser<TKey>
{
  Task<IQueryable<TUser>> GetUsers();
}
```

Sync-over-async is an antipattern in the vast majority of cases. I talk more about the principle of [async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) in an MSDN article.

Comment: Thx for your reply. But IQueryableUserStore is Microsoft.AspNet.Identity interface https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613228(v=vs.108).aspx